How to get image dimensions via Power Automate
I am setting up a Microsoft Power Automate flow that iterates through a series of folders on my desktop. I would like to find all images that are below a certain size (dimensions, not filesize) threshold. How do I access such file metadata in a Power Automate flow? I can only see file properties like these:

I am on desktop, using Windows 11 Pro and Power Automate version 2.42, not sure if that matters. But perhaps it does, since my UI looks different from what I've seen on videos online.

Seems like a pretty basic thing to access file metadata, but I guess there isn't a way for Power Automate Desktop to do this yet - it simply doesn't exist in the manual at this time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/file
I've also learned that Power Automate and Power Automate Desktop are two different products entirely, and things that are trivial in one, may not even feature in the other.
